# How to store all of the data from MySQL into a variable in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I run the following query in phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT firstName, lastName, credits FROM volunteers ORDER BY credits, firstName ASC
```

I get 9 rows as the result.
But when I run the following code in php, the `$storing_data` variable stores the array value of only one row.

```
$query_for_credits_table=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT firstName, lastName, credits FROM volunteers ORDER BY credits, firstName ASC;");
$storing_data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_for_credits_table);
```

What will I have to do to store the complete information in the variable??

Comment: you get a table back, and you want to store it in a variable, do you mean an array or json?

Comment: I want to store the data as an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to loop through the results and build then the array

```
$query_for_credits_table=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT firstName, lastName, credits FROM volunteers ORDER BY credits, firstName ASC;");

if( $query_for_credits_table){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_for_credits_table)) {
        $user = array(
            'firstName' => $row['firstName'],
            'lastName' => $row['lastName'],
            'credits ' => $row['credits ']
        );
    }
    $storing_data[] = $user;
}
```

Comment: Or just use [mysqli_fetch_all()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php).